# jQuery dropdown change event no triggering

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am new to jQuery and having trouble to trigger change event in drop down box.

This is my HTML markup

```
<select id="mini_bookinglocation" name="mini_bookinglocation">
    <option selected="selected" value="">Please Select</option>
</select>
```

This is my `jQuery`

```
$("#mini_bookinglocation").change(function() 
{
    alert(" test ");
});
```

I have tried put this inside the document ready block as well as outside but seems I can't get it working. I don't see the alert coming out.

Also do I need to keep these function withing the document ready section ?

Can anyone help ?

Thanks

Just to add that the values for the above will pass dynamically using jQuery.

Comment: is there any error in browser console?

Comment: you don't have any other options. Then how did u try drop down effect?

Comment: stry adding more options to the select element

Comment: And "yes" on the "need `ready`" part.

Comment: Your code works if there are more options such that a change is possible: http://jsfiddle.net/ErytP/ (The code would need to be in a ready handler _unless_ it is in a script block that appears after the element in question.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. it is because in my code I use jQuery in one place and $ in another place. I was able to google this and just changed all to jQuery and removed all $ and it works. Sorry for not showing the full code but I was able to learn lot by reading all answers.

Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 8):

You have only one value in dropdown. So value is never changed. Thats why `.change` is not called.
Try adding more options in select box.

Also you **should** write the jQuery code inside `document.ready`.

Comment: _"Also you must always write the jQuery code inside document.ready."_ - Always? Definitely not. It will work if it appears in a script block that is _after_ the element in question.

Answer (score 5):

Try adding more options, because change event is fired when there is a change in values. In your case there is no change in values.

```
<select id="mini_bookinglocation" name="mini_bookinglocation">
    <option selected="selected" value="">Please Select</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
   </select>
```

From The [docs](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

> The change event is sent to an element when its value changes. For
>   select boxes, checkboxes, and radio buttons, the event is fired
>   immediately when the user makes a selection with the mouse, but for
>   the other element types the event is deferred until the element loses
>   focus.

*Also do I need to keep these function withing the document ready section ?*

No, there is no need to put the code under ready function because the event is fired when change happens

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RqYtw/)**

Answer (score 1):

Assign change event listener in the document ready function

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#mini_bookinglocation").change(function() {
                alert(" test ");
            });
        });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select id="mini_bookinglocation" name="mini_bookinglocation">
        <option selected="selected" value="">Please Select</option>
        <option value="A">Option A</option>
        <option value="B">Option B</option>
        <option value="C">Option C</option>
        <option value="D">Option D</option>
        <option value="E">Option E</option>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is an **[example](http://jsfiddle.net/axrwkr/BdpyX/)**